# Protractor's cssContainingText cannot find element using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, protractor

I'm writing some tests using JavaScript and Protractor.
Say, I want to find element with class="main-class", like in the following example:

```
<div class="main-class">
   ...
   <div class = "some-class">Search Line</div>
   ...
</div>
```

by text of this element's child - the child could have different attributes and values. The text is stored in the variable, also due to some circumstances I have to find the exact match. I'm trying to do smth like this:

```
let text = 'Search Line';
let getElement= function(text) {
        let reg = new RegExp('^'+text+'$');
        return element(by.cssContainingText('.main-class', reg))}
```

But I always get the same error:

```
No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText(".main-class", "/^Search Line$/")
```

If I change `reg` to `'some string'` - everything works fine.
Seems like cssContainingText just doesn't work with my regex, although protractor documentation says, that it can search by regexp: http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText

Could you please tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`by.cssContainingText` supports RegExp since Protractor [5.2.1](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#521),
If your protractor lower then 5.2.1, the regexp will be treated as string and use `string.indexOf()`, rather than use `RegExp.test()`

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer, I've checked and found out that protractor version I have used was 5.2.0. I've updated to 5.2.1, but error is still there (changed a little): `No element found using locator: by.cssContainingText(".main-class", "__REGEXP__/^Search Line$/")`

Comment: @Atsvetk That error means that protractor can't find the element. That regex with only find the element when the text is **EXACTLY** `Search Line`. Do the elements values change?

Comment: I guess I know what my problem is: There is some more text in some other child elements, so the "total" text of the parent element is bigger, than 1 string. I've changed the regex to `new RegExp('^'+text)` and everything works now, thanks a lot, you saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

A solution for pre 5.2.1 is using xpath:

```
let text = 'Search Line';
let reg = '//*[starts-with(.,\''+text+'\')]';
element(by.xpath(reg)); //how to call element
```

This is functionally equivelant to the regex expression `/^Search Line/`

This will also work after 5.2.1, but you check out **Yong's** answer for that, its much better.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I have to find a parent element, not the child one. The example I provided is not so complicated as a real thing, and I can't just use, for example, `.xpath('..')` several times to get to the parent element... Anyway, that's an interesting proposal, thanks again!